# AngularJS form validation using ngMessages not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I have this ***[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C5YpwE?p=preview)*** with 2 forms. The first one (Form One) is not working and I don't have clue what is wrong, everything seems correct for me. The second one (Form Two) is working.

```
Anyone can help me to find out what is wrong?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you hadn't set an ng-model for your input field in the first form. So I just added it like this:

```
ng-model="main.courier"
```

Here's the updated Plunker showing the fix in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/urauW4a7XJNhyBNoxqDa?p=preview

(I also added an ng-class on the wrapping div for better styling of the validation errors).

Comment: You're right! I knew it was something simple! Thanks a lot!!